# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Malformed function or procedure escape syntax at offset 1

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Currently I am facing issue to fetch, postgresql function data via JDBC in DAO class. Connection is establishing properly.

```
CallableStatement  mngStatement = conn              
                     .prepareCall("{? = CALL SELECT_SEARCH_DETAILS(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");

mngStatement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
mngStatement.setString(2,abc.getContractNumber());
mngStatement.setString(3,abc.getOrderNumber());
mngStatement.setString(4,abc.getShipmentNumber());
mngStatement.setString(5,abc.getShipmentControlNo());
mngStatement.setString(6,abc.getStatusFromDate());
mngStatement.setString(7,abc.getStatusToDate());
mngStatement.setString(8,abc.getSourceSystem());
mngStatement.setString(9,abc.getDestinationSystem());

mngStatement.execute();
rs  = (ResultSet) mngStatement.getObject(1);
```

Getting the error like:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Malformed function or procedure
>   escape syntax at offset 1.

Please help me with your suggestion. Thanks in Advance.

Function :

```
FUNCTION SELECT_SEARCH_DETAILS(
    IN P_CONTARCT_NUM character varying,
    IN P_ORDER_NUM character varying,
    IN P_SHIPMENT_NUM  character varying,
    IN P_SHIP_CON_NUM  character varying,
    IN P_FROM_DATE  character varying,
    IN P_TO_DATE  character varying,
    IN P_SOURCE_SYSTEM character varying,
    IN P_DESTINATION_SYSTEM character varying)
  RETURNS table(CONTRACT_NUMBER text,ORDER_NUMBER text, SHIPMENT_NUMBER text, SCN text, STATUS_CODE text,STATUS_DATE text, LAST_UPDATE_DATE text, SOURCE_SYSTEM text, DESTINATION_SYSTEM text, RFID_FOLLOW_ON_CODE text, UID_INDICATOR text, IVC_SHIPMENT_SEQ_ID text) AS
$BODY$
```

Comment: What does your stored procedure look like ?

Comment: Hi berger, I have updated the function body in the question.

Comment: As someone suggested in a comment, could you try with a lower-case `call` ?

Comment: still same error is coming with lower case 'call'.

Comment: Now I am getting error like:"org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A CallableStatement was executed with an invalid number of parameters". But I am not getting any mismatches here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `CallableStatement`.

Use a regular `PreparedStatement` with `select` statement.

As your function returns a table (a "set") you need to use:

```
select * from SELECT_SEARCH_DETAILS(...);
```

So the full code looks like this:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from SELECT_SEARCH_DETAILS(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

pstmt.setString(1, abc.getContractNumber());
pstmt.setString(2, abc.getOrderNumber());
pstmt.setString(3, abc.getShipmentNumber());
pstmt.setString(4, abc.getShipmentControlNo());
pstmt.setString(5, abc.getStatusFromDate());
pstmt.setString(6, abc.getStatusToDate());
pstmt.setString(7, abc.getSourceSystem());
pstmt.setString(8, abc.getDestinationSystem());

ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```